# nominatim.socket not found for setting up nominatim daemon

Tags: sockets, nominatim

I have in the beginning overlooked the Python frontend and when i want to set up the Nominatim service it doesnt find the socket of nominatim:
Failed to start nominatim.service: Unit nominatim.socket not found.
when i search for the file there is no such file on the system.
Version 4.3.0
Ubuntu server 22.4.3

In which part of the installation scholud the socket be generated?

Thank you in advance!

I searched the system for the file and looked up if somebody else had this problem in the web.